# c# - 405 (Method Not Allowed) when POST from Angular 2 app

Tags: c#, rest, api, angular, post

I'm a bit desperate with this issue. I'm new on angular 2 and .net and I trying to build a simple application. I programmed an api rest in c#. When i call a GET method from angular it works fine, but not POSTmethod. I receive 405 (Method not allowed) all the time, but if i call the post with postman all works. I see lots of issues with the same problem, but they doesn't work for me.
I have CORS enabled.
Here's my code:

> Angular

```
    sendPtipo(delegacion,municipio,ejercicio,recinto,tipo){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let urlPtipo ='http://localhost:50790/ApiProductoTipo/CalculaPTRecinto';
    let body ='delegacion='+delegacion+'&municipio='+municipio+'&recinto='+recinto+'&ejercicio='+ejercicio+'&tipo'+tipo;

return this._http.post(urlPtipo , body , options)
               .map(data => {alert('ok');})
               .catch(this.handleError);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
}

private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}}
```

> Api rest in C#

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using AppName.Models;
using AppName.Service;
using System.Linq;
using AppName.ViewModels;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace Api.Services
{
    // Allow CORS for all origins. (Caution!)
   //[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class ApiProductoTipoController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IProductoTipoService productoTipoService;

        public HttpResponseMessage Options()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
        }

        public ApiProductoTipoController(IProductoTipoService productoTipoService)
        {
            this.productoTipoService = productoTipoService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("~/ApiProductoTipo/CalculaPTRecinto")]
        public HttpResponseMessage CalculaPTRecinto([FromBody]int delegacion, int municipio, int ninterno, int ejercicio, string tipo)
        {        
            if (this.productoTipoService.CalculaPTRecinto(delegacion, municipio, ninterno, ejercicio, tipo) != 0)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
    }}
```

> webapiconfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace Web
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            //Enable cors
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "accept,accesstoken,authorization,cache-control,pragma,content-type,origin", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,TRACE,HEAD,OPTIONS");

            //var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");

            config.EnableCors(cors);

            //Configuramos el MapRoute
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ApiWithAction",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }


    }
}
```

> Log

```
headers:Headers
ok:false
status:405
statusText:"Method Not Allowed"
type:2
url:"http://localhost:50790/ApiProductoTipo/CalculaPTRecinto"
_body:"{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}"
```

Any idea? Thank you for reading!

**Edit:** this was the response of Postman 200 OK

```
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →0
Date →Fri, 26 May 2017 09:48:05 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles →=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcNzAyNTU3MjFKXERlc2t0b3BcQXBpUHJvZHVjdG9UaXBvXFdlYlxBcGlQcm9kdWN0b1RpcG9cQ2FsY3VsYVBUUmVjaW50bw==?=
```

Comment: What does your Postman request look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code seems ok.Try to change code as I have given below :

**Angular**

```
sendPtipo(delegacion: number,municipio: number,ejercicio: number,recinto: number,tipo: string){

        let data = new Object();
        data.delegacion = delegacion;
        data.municipio = municipio;
        data.ejercicio = ejercicio;
        data.recinto = recinto;
        data.tipo = tipo;

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let urlPtipo ='http://localhost:50790/ApiProductoTipo/CalculaPTRecinto';

    return this._http.post(urlPtipo , data , options)
                   .map(data => {alert('ok');})
                   .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }}
```

**API in C#**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;
using AppName.Models;
using AppName.Service;
using System.Linq;
using AppName.ViewModels;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace Api.Services
{
    // Allow CORS for all origins. (Caution!)
   //[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class ApiProductoTipoController : ApiController
    {
        public class myobj{
            public int delegacion { get; set; }
            public int municipio { get; set; }
            public int ejercicio { get; set; }
            public int recinto { get; set; }
            public string tipo { get; set; }

        }

        private readonly IProductoTipoService productoTipoService;

        public HttpResponseMessage Options()
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
        }

        public ApiProductoTipoController(IProductoTipoService productoTipoService)
        {
            this.productoTipoService = productoTipoService;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("~/ApiProductoTipo/CalculaPTRecinto")]
         public HttpResponseMessage CalculaPTRecinto(myobj data)
        {        
            var tipo = data.tipo;
            ...
        }
    }}
```

I was facing the same issue.The actual datatype of data you sre sending can't get at API side.That's why its giving `405 error`.So try to send data as an object and also receive as an object at API side.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you ! That works! But now i have another problem. Instead of use an object i use an array with this structure :
 `let data:Ptipo[] = [];
        data.push({'Delegacion':delegacion,
                   'Municipio':municipio,
                   'Ejercicio':ejercicio,
                   'Tipo_Producto':tipo,                    
                   'Ninterno':recinto});`
but i don't get any value of the params :/

Comment: @Aw3same at server side you don't get value of params?

Comment: Yes, i have the method that you provide to me (`public class myobj`) and then get the value like `var delegacion = data.delegacion;`, but when i debug those params don't have any value

Comment: what do you get in data object in your `ts` file?

Comment: i have a class `ptipo.ts` that have `export class Ptipo {
    Delegacion: Number;
    Municipio: number;
    Ejercicio: Number;
    Tipo_Producto: String;
    Ninterno: Number;  
}`.

Comment: Then, in my `service.ts`, the method post `sendPtipo(delegacion,municipio,ejercicio,recinto,tipo){
        let data:Ptipo[] = [];
        data.push({'Delegacion':delegacion,
                   'Municipio':municipio,
                   'Ejercicio':ejercicio,
                   'Tipo_Producto':tipo,                    
                   'Ninterno':recinto});
        /*...*/
    }`. I'm so noob with this languages, thanks for ur patient!

Comment: it seems you have made model class. Then try to pass model in your method in `service.ts`. On submit button pass whole model instead of individual data , then no need to push data again.directly assign it to data object . e.g. `sendPtipo(data){ }`.Here you will get direct data object.

Comment: Yes, i have the object and the values inside them. 
But in the api, the values that asign to `var delegacion = data.delegacion;` of these object are 0 (number) and null (strings). I don't know if i get bad the values or what..

Comment: It might be issue with your code or values you are sending.